# How to calculate z-score for each column of dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set as:

```
> mydata
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
3  9 10 11 12
4 13 14 15 16
5 17 18 19 20
```

I want to calculate the z-score for each column of the data. I was wondering if I could create "for loops" to calculate standard deviation and mean for each column and then use the z-score formula?

Comment: What is your desired output? A dataframe with the same dimensions as `mydata`, but with Z-scores per column instead of their original values?

Comment: no need of a loop, just `scale(mydata)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do scale(mydate) and it will give you z score of every colm

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on the questions above.
if you have a time series, scale (in my personal opinion) does not do the job.
it will look at the entire series, compute the average, sd, and finally give you z-score.
why is this wrong?
Well, again, because if you have a time series, you're basically looking forward looking data to compute both the mean and the sd.
I haven't found a vectorized solution so far, but only a solution based off look for (hence computationally slow).

Assuming DF is a dataframe with distinct columns, the z-score of each column would be given by:

```
p1 <- matrix(0, nrow(df), ncol(df))
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
        avg_var <- mean(df[1:i, j])
        sd_var  <- sd(df[1:i, j])
        z_sc <- (df[i, j] - avg_var) / sd_var
        p1[i, j] <- z_sc
      }
    }
```